# How to get updated score without page refresh in PHP using API

Tags: php, api

I have PHP code that updates score using API accompanied with a key by `file_get_content` PHP function.

I am getting the score, but every time I have to reload the page to get the updated score.

Can anyone tell me how to refresh the score without page reload? I know PHP server-side script language so definitely I have to refresh my own.

Is there any way to implement node.js here?

PHP code:

```
<?php
$var='xyzxyzxyz'; //My api key

    $cricketMatchesTxt = file_get_contents('http://cricapi.com/api/cricket/?apikey='.$var.' '); // change with your API key
    $cricketMatches = json_decode($cricketMatchesTxt);

    foreach($cricketMatches->data as $item) {
?>
    <h4><?php echo($item->title); ?></h4>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery with ajax to make a call to your php file that will return the json response from the cricapi server to you and then replace the old data with the new one.

As this question is too broad and with little code to help you in more detail I can only point you to: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ so you can do your own research and see how to implement it.

This example might help you to understand how ajax works:
https://www.tutorialscollection.com/jquery-load-how-to-use-jquery-ajax-load-method-with-examples/

Comment: llic  how this will refresh as score get updated ,jquery or ajax will update part of page without refresh whole page only if we perform any action like click button or soemthing .but i need without doing any action direct from api it should show live score.

Comment: You can use jQuery to call ajax within a certain time interval so that you don't need to click on a button to make ajax request. And yes once you  receive the data with ajax, you can use it to update a part of your page that is showing the scores without reloading the page

Comment: So using long polling we can acheive ok , but it will make burden on server because we have to refresh for every 2 seconds  then only it will work ,any idea apart of this long polling.

Comment: If you have such short intervals between the calls to the API than ajax is not the best solution for this. This would probably be better done with node.js or something similar but I'm not that familiar with them.

Answer (score 1):

To change the page in the browser, without loading a new one, you must use client-side JavaScript. There is no way for server-side code to change data it sent in the past.

If you want to get new data from the server (which could be provided with Node.JS but since you are already using PHP, I see no reason to change that), then you need to use Ajax (i.e. a JavaScript triggered HTTP request that does not result in the browser navigating to a new page) followed by DOM Manipulation to insert the data.

Typically you would use the `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch` APIs (native to browsers) for, or libraries like Axios or jQuery (which wrap those APIs), for Ajax.

Then you can use Native DOM or a library like jQuery to change the content of the page the user is looking at without loading a whole new one.

Comment: @MSp — This isn't the right place for an introduction to JavaScript, Ajax, and DOM manipulation tutorial. Fortunately, [many](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics) / [exist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) / [already](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction).